# Android Emulator not working on macOS 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Tags: android, emulator

I am using macOS 10.10.5 (Yosemite), and I when I run apps with emulator I get an error like this:

> Emulator: Sorry, "qemu-system-i386" can not be run on this version of macOS. Qt requires macOS 10.12.0 or later, you have macOS 10.10.5.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: @ScottBiggs - Downvotes do not require a comment to be provided, but one of the many reasons a downvote is typically issued, is due to a lack of research effort.  **If you find the question helpful I encourage you to upvote it.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I am using macOS 10.10.5 (Yosemite), and I when I run apps with emulator I get an error

You are running a version of MacOS that isn’t supported by the Android SDK Emulator which uses QEMU on MacOS.

You need to update your operating system to a version that is supported by QEMU (i.e. MacOS 10.12 or later)

Comment: @ScottBiggs - I was attempting to answer the author's question.  Please keep the commentary section nice and tidy.  Based on the your comment, any comment that is not feedback on how I can improve this answer, will be reported as no longer being needed.